# Clear queued View invalidate (queued by postInvalidateDelayed)

Tags: android

In my onDraw() for a particular custom View, I want to do some animation. So I call postInvalidateDelayed() to queue up the draw of the next animation frame. But if my view gets invalidated from some other piece of code as well, I can end up with multiple queued Invalidates. This results in the animation N times faster than intended.

Is there a way to clear the queued invalidates before posting the new one?

Or determine that there are invalidates already queued?

Or perhaps there is some other way to prevent my animation from speeding up with every additional call to invalidate (outside of the ones being queued)?

```
override fun onDraw(canvas:Canvas){
    if (needToDrawAnimation){
        drawNextScene(canvas)
        postInvalidateDelayed(1000)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I opted to delete my answer b/c it was for `invalidate()`, not `postInvalidate()`. I'll suggest you look at `Handler.postDelayed()`.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion of PropertyAnimator was a good one. I think I will be able to use ObjectAnimator to generate the correct frequency of animation frames ... and then just issue View.Invalidate with each frame. I can start and stop this animator as needed. Thanks. (I will add this as an answer once I have it working).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using an ObjectAnimator to drive the animation. The ObjectAnimator modifies an integer property of my View class (representing the frame index). In the OnDraw() of the View, I decide whether to start/stop the ObjectAnimator. In the setter of the animated property, I call invalidate().

The result is that any call to invalidate() on the View will put it into the correct animation state. Furthermore, the View can stop the animation if it deems appropriate (e.g. if the data the View is displaying indicates so at the time of onDraw()).